# Where can I find software for the Mac Classic?

Tags: mac, software, classic-mac-os, floppy

I just found a really great application: Mini vMac, a Mac Classic emulator (simple and one that actually works). Is there a place where I can find some actual software that was meant for the original Macintosh? I think someone I know might have some boxes of floppies, so would it be possible to copy files off of them? I don't want modern software that was made for emulators. Would the Apple website have some hidden like how they have old System 6+ downloads?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple's website has a page dedicated to [Older Software Downloads](http://www.info.apple.com/support/oldersoftwarelist.html) for systems earlier than 8.1.

(They also still have [a support page for OS 9](http://www.apple.com/support/macos9/), but the Downloads link on this page just links to the current OS X downloads page.)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that they also had other software.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to AppleCare's [Older Software Downloads](http://www.info.apple.com/support/oldersoftwarelist.html) list, there are a few other sites that host old Macintosh software, including [Software for Classic Macs](http://www.jagshouse.com/classicsoftware.html) and [Info-Mac Archive](http://www.info-mac.org/viewforum.php?f=94).

Wikipedia's [list of old Macintosh software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_old_Macintosh_software) should also help you get names of specific applications.

Answer (score 3):

[Macintosh Garden](http://www.macintoshgarden.org/) is another good source.

Answer (score 2):

You can download System 6, System 7 and MacOS 8 and 9 from my ftp server hosted on a 1992 Mac LCII running system 7.0.1:

ftp://oldservers.ddns.net/

Answer (score 1):

And a few classic games: [Cliff Johnson's game site](https://www.fools-errand.com/07-DL/index.htm)